# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Given String is empty or null onClick signup

Tags: java, android

Whenever I tap on signup the the error java.lang.IllegalArgumentException:
Given String is empty or null keeps popping up on the log cat

My Code

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    progressBar = findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
    email = findViewById(R.id.etEmail);
    password = findViewById(R.id.etPassword);
    signup = findViewById(R.id.btnSignup);
    login = findViewById(R.id.btnLogin);
    forgotPass = findViewById(R.id.btnUserForgottPass);

    toolbar.setTitle(R.string.app_name);

    firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

    signup.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                firebaseAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email.getText().toString(), password.getText().toString())
                        .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                                progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                                if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                                    firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser().sendEmailVerification()
                                            .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                                                @Override
                                                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                                                    if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                                                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Registered successfully. Please check your email for verification",
                                                                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                                        email.setText("");
                                                        password.setText("");
                                                    } else {
                                                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, task.getException().getMessage(),
                                                                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                                    }
                                                }
                                            });

                                }
                            }
                        });
            }
    });


    login.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, LoginActivity.class));
        }
    });

    forgotPass.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, ForgotPasswordActivity.class));
        }
    });

}
```

}
 Logcat

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Given String is empty or null
  at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.Preconditions.checkNotEmpty(Unknown Source)at com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(Unknown Source)
        at com.example.patrick.test.MainActivity$1.onClick(MainActivity.java:56) firebaseAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email.getText().toString(), password.getText().toString())"
```

I dont know how to create an argument where if you click the sign up button and email && password is = to null it will show a toast that prompts the user to input their email and password.

*I am Just a beginner at programming.*

Comment: Add an if statement to check email and password are not null or empty before the createUserWith... method. If either are, add a toast to inform the user of this, and return.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No worries, it's pretty straight forward. When you get a little further along, consider your onCreate as a clean startup place, not to be used for wiring up button clicks or handling events. In the mean time, let's work with what you got.

```
signup.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
    progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    String emailStr = email.getText().toString()
     String password = password.getText().toString()
      if(emailStr == null || emailStr.isEmpty()){
            Toast.makeText("Email must not be empty", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
      }else if(password == null || password.isEmpty(){
              Toast.makeText("Password must not be empty", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
      }else{
              firebaseAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email.getText().toString(), password.getText().toString())
                       .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                            progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                            if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                                firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser().sendEmailVerification()
                                        .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                                            @Override
                                            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                                                if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                                                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Registered successfully. Please check your email for verification",
                                                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                                    email.setText("");
                                                    password.setText("");
                                                } else {
                                                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, task.getException().getMessage(),
                                                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                                }
                                            }
                                        });

                            }
                        }
                    });
            }
        }

});
```

I just copied your code and typed directly in here, so if anything is slightly off, it will be minor. The goal is to store string variables with your user entries. Then validate that they are not empty or null and of course if you have requirements that they meet those requirements before you attempt to send it.

If you prefer early returns you can also do it like

```
signup.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
          progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
          String emailStr = email.getText().toString()
          String password = password.getText().toString()
          if(emailStr == null || emailStr.isEmpty()){
                Toast.makeText("Email must not be empty", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                return;
          }

          if(password == null || password.isEmpty(){
                  Toast.makeText("Password must not be empty", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                  return;
          }

          //the rest of the firebase code
```

Comment: Some Minor revisions but... It works. Thank you So much for the help with my project.

Comment: No problem. Glad to help.